# Converting native php to vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a Selection with onchange function. Here is my code in native PHP.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Branch</label>
      <select name="branch"  id="branch_" onChange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control" required>
        <option>Choose your Branch</option> 
        <?php foreach ($branchessss as $key) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $key['branch_id']; ?>"><?php echo $key['branch_name']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Stylist</label>
      <div class="controls" id="statediv">
        <select class="form-control" id="stylistname_" name="stylistname" required>
          <option>--</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can i convert it to Vuejs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then re-write your question showing what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following:

```
//Pass the $branchessss as a prop (lets say branchOptions) to the component
<select v-model="branch">
    <option v-for="option in branchOptions" v-bind:value="option.branch_id">
       {{ option.branch_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```